# Fixed Full Screen Height Outer Container, with Overflowed Content Inside

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, css-position

I have a modal that slides out from the right and takes the full height of the browser window. It has a header, footer, and middle content. If the middle content becomes tall enough, I want it to scroll (overflow: auto). Is this possible?

Here's a screenshot of my modal:

[image]

So essentially, I want the header and footer to remain where they are (header at the top, and footer either at the very bottom, or at the bottom of the content), and if I now resized the browser window pulling the bottom up, I would want to see a scrollbar appear in the middle content once the height of the browser became shorter than the content.

```
.modal-body {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

doesn't seem to do anything.

Here's the JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/707xbabw/2/

Comment: Should be possible with a `max-height` and `overflow:auto` I assume? Do you have a jsfiddle or can you show some code?

Comment: Added a jsfiddle link in the question.

Comment: Maybe it can be done using flexbox?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add height to model body and over-flow auto or scroll

```
demo link
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kanib93/zfh6kzfw/

Comment: I want to do it *without* hard-coding a height for the modal body. The modal body should automatically expand until the content goes past the height of the page.

Answer (score 0):

What does work is putting the `overflow: auto` on the `.modal-content`. But then the close button disappears because it lives outside the overflowed content. To fix this, put it in div higher and it should work as it suppose to:

See: https://jsfiddle.net/707xbabw/7/